# Android Studio - Error: App is crashing on Virtual Device

Tags: android

So, I am a new programmer and also new here on this platform. I have got a Problem. I tried everything like to watch Videos, read older Posts on StackOverflow, but nothing helped me really. That's why I wanted to ask you for help.

This is my Logcat after the crash report:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at de.S8S7.Spiel.onCreate(Spiel.java:32)

And at this point it Shows the error:

```
btnAntwortEins.setOnClickListener(this);
btnAntwortZwei.setOnClickListener(this);
btnAntwortDrei.setOnClickListener(this);
btnAntwortVier.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And yeah, I am not native English speaker.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For this issue, we need to see a little bit more of the code. Can you show where 'btnAntwortEins' and friends are initialised. Also, please include the XML file that contains the buttons. See these guidelines:  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]). Thank you.

Comment: Most likely button is not initialized with findViewById()

Comment: Indeed, the error is that setOnClickListener() cannot be done because the object (button) is null. That is you didn't get the view yet as MoGa said. So you need to make sure the button objects (btnAntwort___) are in use before calling setOnClickListener()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beforde you can set the OnClickListeners, you have to load the instances of the Buttons like this:

```
btnAntwortEins = findViewById(R.id.btnIdAntwortEins);
btnAntwortZwei = findViewById(R.id.btnIdAntwortZwei);
btnAntwortDrei = findViewById(R.id.btnIdAntwortDrei);
btnAntwortVier = findViewById(R.id.btnIdAntwortVier);

btnAntwortEins.setOnClickListener(this);
btnAntwortZwei.setOnClickListener(this);
btnAntwortDrei.setOnClickListener(this);
btnAntwortVier.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The Id (e.g. btnIdAntwortEins) is what you have written into the Id field of each Button in the layout editor.

Comment: I tried the same as you mean, but Nothing changed. The Programm is still crashing..

Comment: You were right in any case! I noticed later that i only used `btnAntwortEins = findViewById(R.id.btnIdAntwortEins);` for Button One. So, i Forget to use ist for the second, third and fourth Button. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

if its only crashing in virtual device then may be u have used google play service in your app and you have not istalled a emulator with play servivce. try to instyall emulator with play services.

[image]

Comment: Sorry that I have not explained in more Detail, in the virtual device as well as connected to the smartphone it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a scenario of having such crash when you dont intialize the button correctly in android.So as you are new to Android development consider these things when you initialize the buttons in the Activity

You can mention the Button Globally like:

```
Button button;
```

you have to give the reference id which you have defined in the xml like;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    githubRepoUrlRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.button);

//mention on click listener after you have given the reference id.

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO task.
            }
        });
```